# Xpages application corrupt "Could not open the editor: Could not parse the .xsp-config file named CustomControls/layout.xsp-config in the...."

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I came into work this morning and one of my Xpages applications appears to be corrupt. Some design elements are duplicated, and when I open up cc or Xpage design elements I get

"Could not open the editor: Could not parse the .xsp-config file named CustomControls/layout.xsp-config in the project C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\KC1_2fScoular\ComputerTips.nsf."

I am not using source control; I have seen a few people comment that Git can cause this problem.

How can I repair the database??

Comment: Does the error still appear if you remove database from Designer's workspace, close Designer and reopen the database in Designer?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Removed it from client and designer workspace, closed both, reopened, and I still got the error.

Comment: You might repair the layout.xsp-config file: open database in Package Explorer and copy this file from an older version (backup). But, it does sound a bit worrying if you say you have duplicated design elements... So, restoring the complete database from backup might be the better approach.

Comment: Knut, I restored a backup, but this page (http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/05/could-not-open-editor-problem-with.html) also help me enormously. the appLayout CC was messed up. Went into the java package and deleted it and all seems to be well now, after I just replaced this design element from the old design.

Comment: Great to hear that your database works again. Was kind of a Monday morning shock for you probably...

Answer (score 2):

I've had that happen before in older versions of Domino Designer. Sometimes closing Designer and restarting solves the problem.

The .xsp-config file can be found in Package Explorer and holds the information to display the custom control in the Controls Palette as well as any custom properties. It can be opened directly from there and opens in the XML editor. In a worst case scenario, you can always delete the properties or other XML entities, then paste back in once it's working again (or add the properties back in using the Properties pane). The .xsp file (the underlying Custom Control) can also be opened in the XML Editor by right-clicking in the Package Explorer and selecting Open With and choosing the XML Editor.

Because of the underlying Eclipse functionality, you can delete an XML-based component - XPage, Custom Control, xsp-config - create a new entry with the same name, and use Compare With > Local History to see previous versions. Local History is stored based on the text file name. So you have a (short-term) back, even without source control.